# E: Version '1.14.0-0ubuntu1.9' for 'nginx' was not found

Tags: ubuntu, docker, nginx

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

ENV NGINX_VERSION 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.9

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx=$NGINX_VERSION

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

trying to create a custom nginx docker image but getting error:

```
E: Version '1.14.0-0ubuntu1.9' for 'nginx' was not found
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx=$NGINX_VERSION' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Answer (score 0):

`apt` repositories usually only have a single version of a package for a given release; in your case, [the `bionic` repositories currently provide version 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.11 of the `nginx` package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+source/nginx).

In practice, this means that you should write your container file as follows:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

In fact, you can save a layer by merging both `apt-get` lines:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl nginx
```

See [Why do previous versions of Debian packages vanish in the package repositories? (highly relevant for version-controlled system configuration)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/544432/86440) for details; Ubuntu repositories have the same behaviour.